# Symfony2 docs on Routing component?

Tags: symfony

I was looking for Routing Component's documentation, explicitly which types of parameters it accepts.

For example, the `type: annotations` in my just created app's routing.yml made me want to look what other types are out there, but there is no docs on it. I can only find the documentation in the Book and a little bit in Components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Loader types**

Main types of routing loaders are described in [the component's docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#load-routes-from-a-file). It mentions quite a few loaders:

- [YamlFileLoader](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.html)
- [XmlFileLoader](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/XmlFileLoader.html)
- [PhpFileLoader](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/PhpFileLoader.html)
- [ClosureLoader](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/ClosureLoader.html)
- [AnnotationFileLoader](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/AnnotationFileLoader.html), [AnnotationClassLoader](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/AnnotationLoader.html) & [AnnotationDirectoryLoader](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/AnnotationDirectoryLoader.html)

You'll find all the core loaders in the [Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader namespace](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader.html)

It's all based on [Config's component loaders](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader.html), so it's worth if you also read about [the Config component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/introduction.html).

Each loader's [`supports()`](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php#L96-L99) method will tell you in which circumstances the loader is actually used. For example, for the `YamlFileLoader` it's:

```php
public function supports($resource, $type = null)
{
    return is_string($resource) 
       && 'yml' === pathinfo($resource, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) 
       && (!$type || 'yaml' === $type);
}
```

You can see it looks at resource's extension and type.

**Custom loaders**

You can implement your own loaders by implementing the [Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/LoaderInterface.html).

Read more about it in the [How to Create a custom Route Loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html) cookbook. It actually explains quite a lot on how routing loaders work. Have a look at some 3rd party loaders too, such as the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/tree/master/Routing/Loader)'s one.

**How to wire it all together**

Have a look at the generated container in the Symfony Standard Edition to see how the full stack framework wires it all together. It should look similar to:

```php
/**
 * Gets the 'routing.loader' service.
 *
 * This service is shared.
 * This method always returns the same instance of the service.
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\DelegatingLoader A Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\DelegatingLoader instance.
 */
protected function getRouting_LoaderService()
{
    $a = $this->get('file_locator');
    $b = $this->get('annotation_reader');

    $c = new \Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Routing\AnnotatedRouteControllerLoader($b);

    $d = new \Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderResolver();
    $d->addLoader(new \Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\XmlFileLoader($a));
    $d->addLoader(new \Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader($a));
    $d->addLoader(new \Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\PhpFileLoader($a));
    $d->addLoader(new \Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\AnnotationDirectoryLoader($a, $c));
    $d->addLoader(new \Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\AnnotationFileLoader($a, $c));
    $d->addLoader($c);

    return $this->services['routing.loader'] = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\DelegatingLoader($this->get('controller_name_converter'), $this->get('monolog.logger.router', ContainerInterface::NULL_ON_INVALID_REFERENCE), $d);
}
```

The key here is the [LoaderResolver](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/LoaderResolver.html) which takes care of finding an appropriate loader for a type of configuration.

Comment: Thanks, seems much more complicated of what I thought. I was hoping something like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html it says that routing configs should be there but that part is missing Maybe I should file a bug?

Comment: The question is why do you need it. All the routing types are mentioned in the docs by name, and Symfony does a pretty good job guessing the type too. Usually if you need to do anything custom you know your stuff.

Comment: I was just curious, I like to know what configs can I set just in case there is some nice features I could use but didn't know of. Thanks for the answer. I didn't know that it guesses the 'type'. What happens if I specify `type: yaml` for example?

Comment: If you specify the type, it will use the specified type :)